# save imported photo within in xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, save

I'm still a bit confused on models and saving data, perhaps someone could help me out.  I have a page where user can import a photo from there camera roll.As soon as I move to next page its gone again.  I can save text data in a NString from text boxes but im unsure how to do this with an image.  Image is displayed in UI webview.

xcode 4.3

```
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Of all Try to post some code of ur problem. it makes us help u better.

Okay from what i have speculated the problem is that u are loosing the image when u push to the new view . well i had this problem and i solved it using Singleton Class. it sorta create Global elements and u can store values which u prefer to hold. including Images, Class Objects (u name it)

U can hold as much values as u want and u dont even have to store it in ur Library.

Try Reading Singleton Classes On Internet i m sure our good friend Google will certainly help u out

**EDITED -------- About SINGLETON**

okay since u have read about Singleton. u might have notice why do we use Singleton Classes, The Major purpose of Singleton is to hold global variables, but u know that dont u.!!! so about ur issues, when u pick an image (either from Camera or Photo Galary) it will return to u an Object of UIImage.

u must have a Class of Singleton Some thing Like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject

{
        //Global  Variables

        //UImage Instance that will Store The Image From Picker
        UIImage *photoPicked;    
}

//Getter And Setter
@property (nonatomic,retain)  UIImage *photoPicked ;

//Shared SIngleton CLass
+(Singleton*)sharedSingletonController;
@end
```

And the M file will look something like this

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton
@synthesize imagePicked;

//Class Function For SingleTon

+(Singleton*)sharedSingletonController{

    static Singleton *sharedSingleton;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!sharedSingleton){
            sharedSingleton = [[Singleton alloc]init];
        }
    }

    return sharedSingleton;
}

//I don't want a re-initialization for these variables
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {


        }
    return self;
}



@end
```

now all u got to do is to call the sharedSingletonController function in the class where  want to use the singleton Image variable like and yeah dont forgot to create an Object of Singleton Class

Some thing like that

```
Singleton *yourSingletonObj = [Singleton sharedSingletonController];
```

now u can store ur image in singleton like

```
yourSingletonObj.image = (YOUR IMAGE FROM PICKER);
```

Now the image will be saved in ur Singleton object. So when it will not be lost and u can use it anytime u and in any class u like

Cheers
Let ME Know if it Worked
W

Comment: Code posted, researching singleton classes, will report back if i fathom it, thanks for your advice

Comment: Ok ive read up on singleton classes and still no further forward, all i want to do is stop the photo vanishing when i navigate away from the view.  You said you had this problem and solved it, perhaps you would be as kind as to elaborate in new programmer terms?

Comment: Thanks again for you help, ive created the singleton class, understand the principal behind using the class to store global variables and im nearly there thanks to your help. I dont understand the singleton object part `Singleton *yourSingletonObj = [Singleton sharedSingletonController];` & `yourSingletonObj.image = (YOUR IMAGE FROM PICKER);` i keep getting error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: where do i add this? the singleton class or  class for tpage i want to save the image, ive tried both and get errors

Comment: also whats an object of a singleton class?

Comment: okay the class in which u are picking up the image will have the singleton object. just to be sure. Create the Singleton Object in the h file of that class. and in the view did load call it like yourSingletonObj = [Singleton sharedSingletonController]; and when u are picking up ur image save it in yourSingletonObj.imagePidked (sorry i made a mistake)

Comment: object of the singleton class is the object through which u will set the values that lie with in the singleton class.

Comment: Wow,  now im even more confused, i really appreciate you trying to help me out here but it just makes no sense, thought i was getting somewhere with the singleton class created but just cannot get my head around what the other bits mean about calling objects etc. Im sure it simple when you know how, I just dont know why its so difficult to save 1 picture in xcode. Ive tried and tried with this and am now totally stuck.

Comment: send me ur code i ll have a look at it @waleed.khan@cubixlabs.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10852/discussion-between-brainstorms-and-jsa986)

Comment: Thank so much for your patience and help, so grateful!